# Tell Visual C++ where to look for DLLs

Tags: visual-c++, dll, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-debugging

I can set global search directories for headers and libraries in VC++ Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions.

But what about DLLs? Can I do this through VC++ itself which would be preferable?

Comment: `Executable files` in the same dialog box?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not VC++ which will search for dlls but it is your application which will search for dlls. Here is how it works

Your application search for the dll in the following folder
 system - system32 - windows - folder specified in path - application directory

If the dll is not found on any of these locations, it will raise an error.

To resolve this, you can always specify the exact path of dll in the application itself. Refer to this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx for further explanation.

Comment: Ah, so I can't temporarily add a path during debugging then.

Comment: Yes you can, put the debug path between #define precompiler directives to specify conditional compilation of your debug version

Comment: Using precompiler directives will ensure that your release version will not have that code.

Comment: I don't want to go hacking paths into my code, that's horrible!

Comment: Hack ? I just have suggested a way that will allow you to use the dll of your choice for debugging.

Comment: I was after a way to temporarily add a path to the environment only during debugging or something but that appears NOT to be possible. Since I don't use LoadLibrary it would be ugly in my context to add it for this problem!